# How to inject a service in another service in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use the logging service in another service in order to trouble shoot that service.

My config.yml looks like this:

```
services:
    userbundle_service:
        class:        Main\UserBundle\Controller\UserBundleService
        arguments: [@security.context]

    log_handler:
        class: %monolog.handler.stream.class%
        arguments: [ %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.jini.log ]


    logger:
        class: %monolog.logger.class%
        arguments: [ jini ]
        calls: [ [pushHandler, [@log_handler]] ]
```

This works fine in controllers etc. however I get no out put when I use it in other services.

Any tips?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You pass service id as argument to constructor or setter of a service.

Assuming your other service is the `userbundle_service`:

```
userbundle_service:
    class:        Main\UserBundle\Controller\UserBundleService
    arguments: [@security.context, @logger]
```

Now Logger is passed to `UserBundleService` constructor provided you properly update it, e.G.

```
protected $securityContext;
protected $logger;

public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, Logger $logger)
{
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Comment: public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

Comment: You don't have $logger argument in constructor.

Comment: so for every injectable service, it has to be included this way? Seems an awful lot of work to just get log messages.

Comment: protected $securityContext;
     protected $logger;

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, Logger $logger )
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

Comment: Services are just normal PHP objects, how else would you want to inject them? :)

Comment: What exactly do you expect to be 'output'?

Comment: In the latest version of Symfony, there has to be quotes around the service name, as in: `arguments: ['@security.context', '@logger']`

Answer (score 12):

#### For Symfony 3.3, 4.x, 5.x and above, the easiest solution is to use Dependency Injection

You can directly inject the service into another service, (say `MainService`)

```
// AppBundle/Services/MainService.php
// 'serviceName' is the service we want to inject
public function __construct(\AppBundle\Services\serviceName $injectedService)  {
    $this->injectedService = $injectedService;
}
```

Then simply, use the injected service in any method of the MainService as

```
// AppBundle/Services/MainService.php
public function mainServiceMethod() {
    $this->injectedService->doSomething();
}
```

And viola! You can access any function of the Injected Service!

#### For older versions of Symfony where autowiring does not exist -

```
// services.yml
services:
    \AppBundle\Services\MainService:
        arguments: ['@injectedService']
```

Comment: I've tried this so that 2 services can reference each other but you end up with a circular reference issue.

Comment: @Adambean, I have the same. Did you figure out a way to handle this?

Comment: @Allart Nope, though since largely using Symfony 5/6 and rethinking how I define services I've not needed two services to directly depend on each other.
If you really really really need to do this then you'd have to do it the classic way whereby you give both services the container instance, and use `$otherService = $this->container->get("the_other_service")`. (You can satisfy IntelliSense, PHPStan, or similar by putting `/** @var OtherService $otherService */` before that.) Still probably warrants a rethink in how your application code is structured though.

Comment: @Adambean, tnx for the help. I belive I was just doing a bad design practice. Currently I created a `GeneralService` service class. Since it was only 2 lines of code to remove to make my error go away, and these lines where general functions. So it kinda makes sense now, but soon or later I might get into the same issues I think. Would be nice if there was a good example or examples of how you should build your Services in bigger projects. To make sure you aviod those type of issues. Anyway, problem solved rn for me.

Comment: Depends on what your services are doing. If you're making service classes just to segregate stateless functionality Symfony suggest that you make these functions static so you don't need to inject them anywhere at all.

Answer (score 0):

More versatile option, is to once create a trait for the class you would want to be injected. For instance:

Traits/SomeServiceTrait.php

```
Trait SomeServiceTrait
{
    protected SomeService $someService;

    /**
     * @param SomeService $someService
     * @required
     */
    public function setSomeService(SomeService $someService): void
    {
        $this->someService = $someService;
    }
}
```

And where you need some service:

```
class AnyClassThatNeedsSomeService
{
    use SomeServiceTrait;

    public function getSomethingFromSomeService()
    {
        return $this->someService->something();
    }
}
```

The class will autoload due to @required annotation. This generaly makes it much faster to implement when you want to inject services into numerous classes (like event handlers).