# Symfony2: Better way to inject services between another services

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I've read some post regarding this subject but I'm still wondering if there is a better way to "auto inject" any service. I mean, if I have a namespace called person services (which includes personalDataService, relativesDataService, etc) it'd be great if I could do something like this:

```
services:
    Person.personalData:
        class:        Main\UserBundle\Services\PersonalDataService
        arguments: [Person.*]

    Person.relativesData:
        class:        Main\UserBundle\Services\RelativesataService
        arguments: [Person.*]
```

I know that is possible to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801541/how-to-inject-a-service-in-another-service-in-symfony) but I'm looking for other "efficient" way

Comment: Just a note, but no solution: Be careful not to create circular references (ServiceA requires ServiceB, which requires ServiceA). Your example mentioned above would very likely result in a circular reference.

Comment: You are totally right, but I'm looking for something like services.person.* (C++) or services.person (Javascript)

Comment: Symfony 2 doesn't offer autowiring (automatically inject the services you need), but there are other containers that can. For example PHP-DI integrates with SF2: http://php-di.org/doc/definition.html

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli thank you, it's exactly what I needed, I'm gonna take a look and will be back with a bunch of questions

Answer (score 1):

There is not better way. The best way is the way that is described in your own [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801541/how-to-inject-a-service-in-another-service-in-symfony)...

#### Why is that?

You don't want to inject unneeded services because if you start injecting services that you won't use then your destroying your own app with clutter and it will more or less slow down. So basicly using the way as described in the post above is the best way because you will be wondering for yourself again what do I really need and only put in the neccesary stuff... If that means later on you have to change your config and service constructor because you need an extra service injected so it is.

I hope this answers your question...

Comment: I agree, but, I think this is something that S2 should be handle, I mean, S2 should be smart enough to load just the services which are needed

Comment: It won't be clear anymore what your service has for kind of configuration... If you create a new service in the same namespace it would be automatically added in the other services making it way unclear what the service really has injected and like stated above circular references is going to be a huge problem then.

Comment: Don't think so. Many languages do the same, and they still have a very good performance.

Comment: Symfony isn't a language it is a framework based on a language and that's a major difference... A framework shouldn't do things behind my back or at least not too much.

Comment: Javascript doesn't do that by itself, but frameworks like AngularJS or EmberJS do that. It's what I mean