# Inject one service inside another service

Tags: symfony

How can I inject one service inside another in Symfony 3.4?

Assuming I have this structure:

```
AppBundle
    Service
        ServiceOne.php
        ServiceTwo.php
```

My services.yml looks like:

```
services:
    ...
    AppBundle\Service\serviceOne:
        arguments: [...]

    service_one:
      alias: AppBundle\Service\serviceOne

    AppBundle\Service\ServiceTwo:
        arguments: ["@logger", "@service_one"]
```

This gives me an error:

```
[2018-07-31 10:37:43] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "ServiceOne" from namespace "AppBundle\Service". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?" at /symfony/var/cache/dev/ContainerKoj7t1p/getServiceOneService.php line 12 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ClassNotFoundException(code: 0): Attempted to load class \"ServiceOne\" from namespace \"AppBundle\\Service\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for another namespace? at /symfony/var/cache/dev/ContainerKoj7t1p/getServiceOneService.php:12)"} []
```

ServiceTwo.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ServiceTwo {

    private $logger;
    private $serviceOne;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, ServiceOne $serviceOne) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->serviceOne = $serviceOne;
    }
    ...
```

I already tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801541/how-to-inject-a-service-in-another-service-in-symfony) It seems it is for an older version of symfony.

And I cleared cache as well.

Comment: Is that single double quote in your services.yml (last line) only a typo? And the lower case of `serviceOne` class name?

Comment: yes it is type. I updated it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject a service in another service in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801541/how-to-inject-a-service-in-another-service-in-symfony)

Comment: According to the location of the error, it is not inside the construction of the ServiceTwo object, but inside your getServiceOneService.php.

Comment: @EneaDume Does not look like duplicate of that question to me, as OP tries it exactly to do as described there, but still gets an error message.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht yes, indeed but this file is created by symfony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. check Typos. The file ServiceOne.php should contain one class ServiceOne and should be named in service.yml as ServiceOne (with namespace)
2. you should not define a service twice, AppBundle\Service\ServiceOne: ~ will fit
3. you should active autowiring. this means you don't need to configure thoses services. Only if you need public usage. But than you still dont need to confige the arguments

Look here Autowiring : https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html
and here autoloading: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service

Comment: 2. How to pass arguments to __construct method when I use this ` AppBundle\Service\ServiceOne: ~`

Comment: you have done it already bei defining the contructor. symfony will look up the type from the container and put in the right dependency.  so you have nothing to do else then:  __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, ServiceOne $serviceOne)

Comment: Thanks, It works now. But I don't quite understand why it doesn't work with explicitly passed arguments.

Comment: if you want to parse them explicitiy, you need to wire them with the hole namespace/classname. you are welcome

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing above, isn't it?

Comment: no you typed :    arguments: ["@logger", "@service_one"],  I mean   arguments: ["@logger", "AppBundle\\Service\\ServiceOne"] dont forget to double the backslash

Comment: No need for double back slashes or any of that stuff.  The original error was from the autoloader.  serviceOne is not the same as ServiceOne.  At some point you must have fixed this.